# Is "what's the point?" the same as asking "what is the meaning of life"?

Tags: meaning-of-life, camus

Is "what's the point?" the same as asking "what is the meaning of life"? I know I said both phrases, so I should know right? But I feel the former much more than the latter. Is it absurd? If so, is Camus just "the bible" on how to respond to the absurd? I'm not sure I can be a true absurdist with my quasi religious beliefs.

Is having meaning in life enough to believe and feel that there is a point to life?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why so? Asking "what's the point?" means to ask [the reason for doing something](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/whats-the-point-of-something#:~:text=%22The%20point%22%20of%20something%20is,What's%20the%20point%20of%20Facebook%3F).

Comment: Good comment thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA so depends on if life is action. Anyway I ask just one question and then suggest an answer can be found in Camus, that's all.